# How to add key-value pair to object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

If I have a document with the following basic structure:

```
{
  ...
  Monday: { a:1, b:2 },
  Tuesday: { c:3, d:4 }
  ...
}
```

Am I able to 'push' an additional key:value pair to Monday's value? Result would be:

```
{
  Monday: { a:1, b:2, z:8 },
  Tuesday: { c:3, d:4 }
  ...
}
```

The `$push` operator seems to only work for arrays.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just do something like that

```
db.foo.update({"_id" :ObjectId("...") },{$set : {"Monday.z":8}})
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this might be irrelevant to the question but as a matter of fact, I opened this page because I was looking for an exact query with `mongoose`. here is my answer with mongoose.

If we have an abstract model (mongoose schema) named `week` in our javascript application then the code will be:

```js
// javascript with mongoose

...

const key = "z";

const KeyValue = 8;

await week.updateOne({
                _id,           // mongoDb document id
              },
              {
                $set:{
                       [`Monday.${key}`]: KeyValue,
                     },
              },
              {
                upsert: true   // options
              },     
);

...
```

Answer (score 2):

How to ***add a new key:value*** pair **to all existing objects of a mongoDB documents**

**Old Key and Value Pairs**

```
> db.students.find().pretty();
 { "_id" : ObjectId("601594f5a22527655335415c"), "name" : "Doddanna" }                                                                                                  
 { "_id" : ObjectId("601594f5a22527655335415d"), "name" : "Chawan" }
```

**Update New Key and Value Pairs Using updateMany() and $set**

```
> db.students.updateMany({},{$set:{newKey1:"newValue1", newKey2:"newValue2", newKeyN:"newValueN"}});
 { "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 2, "modifiedCount" : 2 }
```

**Have a look on Updated pretty result**

```
> db.students.find().pretty();
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("601594f5a22527655335415c"),
    "name" : "Doddanna",
    "newKey1" : "newValue1",
    "newKey2" : "newValue2",
    "newKeyN" : "newValueN"
   }
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("601594f5a22527655335415d"),
    "name" : "Chawan",
    "newKey1" : "newValue1",
    "newKey2" : "newValue2",
    "newKeyN" : "newValueN"
    }
```

> 

Answer (score -8):

```
var json = {
    Monday: { a:1, b:2 },
    Tuesday: { c:3, d:4 } }

json['Monday']['z'] = 8;

console.log(json);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question, regarding the operation in MongoDB. The document in the question refers to a document(similar to a row) in MongoDB.